# why i am getting this error?can anyone help me...?

Tags: python, django, user-input, mysql-python

## user registration using mysql django

*This is the error  im getting and can't find to resolve it.Can anyone help me, i'm using python django and mysql as database with a custom user model...?*

```
AttributeError at /accountregister/
'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'
Request Method: POST**strong text**
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accountregister/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'
Exception Location: /home/akshay/Django/mysite/account/views.py, line 20, in register
Python Executable:  /home/akshay/Django/my_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/akshay/Django/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 16 Feb 2022 06:38:41 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/akshay/Django/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/akshay/Django/mysite/account/views.py, line 20, in register
        user=Newuser.objects.create_user(username=username,Email=Email,pwd1=pwd1,pwd2=pwd2,gender=gender) …
▶ Local vars
```

*this is my views.py*

```
        
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import *
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages

def index(request):
    return render(request,'accounts/index.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['uname']
        Email = request.POST['email']
        pwd1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pwd2 = request.POST['pass2']
        gender=request.POST['gend']
        user=Newuser.objects.create_user(username=username,Email=Email,pwd1=pwd1,pwd2=pwd2,gender=gender)
        user.save()
        messages.success("user saved successfully....!")

        return render(request,'accounts/register.html')

    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/register.html')
```

*this is my models.py...................*

```
class Newuser(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pwd=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

*this is my urls.py........................*

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/',views.register, name='register')   
]
```

Comment: Why do you think that `Newuser.objects.create_user` is a thing?!

Comment: should i change Newuser to User  in both models and views or is somethingwrong with **create_user**

Comment: You should probably start reading here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: i don't want to use or customize the django user model i already created an user table in db that's what i was told to do.. i'm truly a beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `create` instead of `create_user`:

```
      user=Newuser.objects.create(
            username=username,
            Email=Email,
            pwd=pwd1,
            gender=gender)
```

`pwd1=pwd1` and `pwd2=pwd2` will not work here since Newuser doesn't have fields named `pwd1` and `pwd2`.

Also: Comments about taking some tutorial first may seem harsh, but they are kinda right. You can start with official django tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

or some tutorials on YT. At first, many things will be wierd, but after some time it will be like second nature.

Comment: thanks brother that's solved it.. and yeah i'm learning from django doc and yt ...

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Can you mark my answer as accepted answer?